# Exim queue in WHM

Tags: centos, exim, queue

I've got the centos server with WHM. The mail server is exim. I need exim put all messages in queue and not sending directly.Though I've added the `queue_only` option to exim configuration and the messages are collected in the queue now. Afterwards I've found out that someone is calling `exim -q` to process the queue every once in a while. I've found the following cron job:

`0 6 * * * /scripts/exim_tidydb > /dev/null 2>&1`

which I beleive has been used to process the exim queue. Also I suspect that script was installed alongside with WHM. Surely I've commented it out and was expecting everything to work just fine. But that didn't happen. I still get the exim queue processed once in a while.

Am I missing anything? What may cause my exim queue to process?

Here is `cat /etc/exim.conf | grep queue`

```
queue_only
deliver_queue_load_max = 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exim_tidydb shouldn't cause a queue run, it just cleans up the hints files

The exim daemon itself might be causing the queue runs depending on the options its started with.  Does it have a `-q` specified (like `-q30m`)?

If you really, really don't want it to deliver anything while you're looking into this, try setting `hold_domains = *`